# Correct way of deleting items in a numbered list?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have a numbered list in `org-mode` like

```
1. A   
2. B   
3. C  
4. D
```

Now when I kill the second line the list incorrectly gets ordered as,

```
1. A   
3. C  
4. D
```

instead of

```
1. A   
2. C  
3. D
```

I know I can always re-order the list before deleting something, but for long lists this becomes a hassle.

Is there a smarter way to avoid this?

Comment: Why not kill the line and `C-c C-c` to reorder the list after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can kill such lines with no fear in mind. Just use C-c C-c afterwards, or S-right and S-left to go back to the previous list style (with up-to-date numbers).